# spark-submit ClassNotFound Exception with Maven

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I realize there are related questions with this one, but I just can't get my code to work.

I am running a Spark Streaming application in standalone mode, with the master node in my Windows host and a worker in an Ubuntu virtual machine.
 Here is the problem: when I run spark-submit, this is what shows up:

```
 >spark-submit --master spark://192.168.56.1:7077 --class spark.example.Main  C:/Users/Manuel Mourato/xxx/target/ParkMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Warning: Skip remote jar C:/Users/Manuel.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.example.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
    at   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I created this jar file with Maven, using "package" in IntelliJ.
This is how I am setting up my SparkStreaming Context:

```
 SparkConf sparkConfiguration= new SparkConf().setAppName("ParkingDataAnalysis").setMaster("spark://192.168.56.1:7077");
 JavaStreamingContext sparkStrContext=new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConfiguration, Durations.seconds(1));
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You've got space in folder name, please add quotes (") and try again

`spark-submit --master spark://192.168.56.1:7077 --class spark.example.Main  "C:/Users/Manuel Mourato/xxx/target/ParkMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

One more, from docs: a`pplication-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes.`

So please copy your file to HDFS or to **the same** location on all nodes. It would be difficult in combination of Linux and Windows ;) I strongly recommend setting up HDFS

Comment: @manuelmourato please see update, I forgot about one, but important, thing