# Create hadoop 2 node cluster between Windows host and Ubuntu guest VM

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing

I have a JAR file that I want to share between a Windows host and my virtualbox guest machine, with Ubuntu. Because these two OS need to share the same directory (directory needs to have the same name for both), the only way I found to do this is to create an hdfs directory, that is, a 2 node cluster with the same hdfs directory.

I have managed to setup a single node cluster for my Windows host and Ubuntu VM separetly, and that works correctly for both. But now, I want to do it in a multi-cluter fashion. I tried following the instructions in this link http://doctuts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hadoop.html#multi-node-installation , but it didn't work ( when I start the master node, it does not detect the VM node.
 I set up an SSH passwordless connection correctly, but I think it may not be working because of my configurations. Here are the three files that I changed to try and make the 2 node cluster:

```
core-site.xml

<configuration>
  <property>

   <name>fs.default.name</name>

      <value>hdfs://192.168.1.2:54310</value> 

   </property>
 </configuration>


hdfs-site.xml


<configuration>
 <property>

   <name>dfs.replication</name>

   <value>2</value>

</property>



</configuration>


mapred-site.xml

<configuration>

  <property>
   <name>mapreduce.job.user.name</name>
   <value>%USERNAME%</value>
   </property>

    <property>
     <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
     <value>yarn</value>
     </property>

      <property>
       <name>yarn.apps.stagingDir</name>
       <value>/user/%USERNAME%/staging</value>
       </property>

        <property>
         <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
         <value>192.168.1.2:54311</value>
         </property>
</configuration>
```

Again, the single node clusters work well, but it doesn't detect the Ubuntu VM.

Can someone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: HDFS just to share simple files (or sync directories)  between host and guest VM seems like overkill.

Comment: The problem in this case is that my jar file needs to be in a shared directory between the host and guest, which would be easy if they had the same OS. But since it is berween Windows and Ubuntu, Ubuntu doesn't recognize directories like `C://...`, same for `\home\....` with Windows

Comment: This is a follow up to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873502/spark-submit-classnotfound-exception-with-maven

Comment: You are running a VM. You can mount a shared folder between them. And, yes, Ubuntu can actually access a `smb://` Windows shared directory

Comment: And HDFS nor Ubuntu are required to use Spark

Comment: And that Hadoop installation link you found is really, really outdated. It installs Java 6 and Hadoop 1.2, whereas the latest Spark requires Hadoop 2.6 and Java 8

Comment: @cricket_007 , thank you so much. Regarding the last two comments, I know, I noticed that too, and am using hadoop2.6 and java 8. The hadoop configurations part was what I needed help with, so I started reading from there.
About the `smb://`, I did not know about that. I already have a shared folder between them, I will try to put the JAR in that directory and see if it works.

Comment: In any case, I do want to learn how to set up a multi node cluster with hadoop, so I will leave this question here regardless.

Comment: Personally, I use Ambari's automated installer. Super simple.

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm trying to use a `smb://` like you suggested, but I ran into an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050075/cannot-access-shared-folder-in-ubuntu-virtualbox-from-host    Would you be able to check it out? Thank you so much.